# Need an Regex for an ProductID

Tags: regex, vb.net

The regex must fulfill these desirements.

An capital A. Then followed by 3 or more optional chars.
The regex must end on a Capital X or Y or Z.

Must fullfill:

```
A3546sdfsdf6546sdf654Z
A123qze46548X
```

Must not fulfill:

```
A123qze46548XY
A123qze46548XYZ
```

This is what I got but its not working:

```
A.{3,}([X]|[Y]|[Z])
```

with this regex it will also fulfill

```
 A123qze46548XY
 A123qze46548XYZ
```

I don't like that..I'm doing something wrong with the Or operator I guess.

any help ?

Thanx

Comment: Which regular expression engine do you use? (Which programming language do you use ?)

Comment: I'm using an regex tester which has been build in vb.net

Answer (score 2):

Try following regular expression:

```
^A.{2,}[^XYZ][XYZ]$
```

- `[^XYZ]` matches any character that is not `X`, `Y` or `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^A.{3,}\d([X]|[Y]|[Z])$
```

If you specifically don't want X or Y or Z before the last X|Y|Z, but all other characters are OK then do this:

```
^A.{3,}(?<![XYZ])[XYZ]$
```

where: 
  `?<!` is a negative lookbehind.

Comment: Thanx bro! Your answer is also correct! But I hope you understand that falsetru was a lil faster! But hey thanx for the respondage bro! peace

Comment: @Fosa - yup falsetru was quicker and simpler.

Comment: @Fosa - there is a tweak depending on whether the number before the last X|Y|Z will always be a digit. See my second regex - don't know if it is needed for your case.

Comment: yes indeed. I think I was a lil vage when explaining my question. It is not a must that before the X or Y or Z it  has to be a digit. this line "AoknY" Must validate too. Now it does not :(! An capital A followed by 3 or more charachters and must end with Y or Z Or x... ?

Comment: @Fosa - in that case, the second regex in my answer will work for you - it validates AoknY.